# Convert JSON to a Multilevel Bulleted List Using JS

Tags: javascript, json

Can some one help me make the following JSON data:

```
{
 "main": {
  "label":"Main",
  "url":"#main"
 },
 "project": {
  "label":"Project",
  "url":"#project"
 },
 "settings": {
  "label":"Settings",
  "url":"#settings",
  "subnav":[
  {
   "label":"Privacy",
   "url":"#privacy"
  },
  {
   "label":"Security",
   "url":"#security"
  },
  {
   "label":"Advanced",
   "url":"#advanced"
  }
  ]
 }
}
```

into the following bullets list using JS? Assuming you don't know what the first nodes are call labeled (e.g. "main", "project" <- these will be dynamically generated):

- Main (#main)
- Project (#project)
- Settings (#settings)

  - Privacy (#privacy)
  - Security (#security)
  - Advanced (#advanced)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's not use HTML string-hacking, shall we? That would break as soon as any of the data had characters like `<` or `&` in (or `"` in attribute values). Use DOM methods and you don't have to worry about character escaping:

```
function createNav(navs) {
    var ul= document.createElement('ul');
    for (name in navs) {
        var nav= navs[name];
        var a= document.createElement('a');
        a.href= nav.url;
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nav.label));
        var li= document.createElement('li');
        li.id= 'nav-'+name;
        li.appendChild(a)
        if ('subnav' in nav)
            li.appendChild(createNav(nav.subnav));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    return ul;
}

document.getElementById('navcontainer').appendChild(createNav(jsondata));
```

Most JS frameworks offer shortcuts to make this a bit less wordy. For example with jQuery:

```
function createNav(navs) {
    var ul= $('<ul>');
    for (name in navs) {
        var nav= navs[name];
        var li= $('<li>', {id: name});
        li.append($('<a>', {href: nav.url, text: nav.label}));
        if ('subnav' in nav)
            li.append(createNav(nav.subnav));
        ul.append(li);
    }
}

$('#navcontainer').append(createNav(jsondata));
```

Note that either way, you're using an Object literal which means you get no control over the order the list of navs comes out. You have no guarantee that `main` will be above `project`. If you want a defined order, you will have to have the returned JSON data be an array.

Comment: Thanks, the first version of the code works but the jQuery version doesn't.

Comment: for the jquery version, just add `return ul;` in the end

Answer (score 1):

My code is on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw2nR/1/).

As JSON parser I used [this one](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js).

The main code is a recursive renderer of the parsed JSON:

```
function recursive_parse(result) {
    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var k in result) {
        html = html + '<li>' + result[k].label + ' (' + result[k].url + ')';
        html = html + recursive_parse(result[k].subnav);
        html = html + '</li>';
    }
    html = html + '</ul>';
    return html;
}

var result = json_parse($("div#test1111").html());
var html = recursive_parse(result);
$("div#test2222").html(html);
```